# Python mean of subset of a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to obtain a list of means from a list. To demonstrate, in my example I have list called listA.

```
listA = [1,7,8,9,0,7,8,9,9,3,5,3,4,5,3]
```

Now I want to create a list of means with another list I have to specify which index ranges I want to take the mean of. I use indexmeans to do that:

```
indexmeans = [3, 4,3,5]
```

So my desired list of means would take the first '3' numbers of listA which have a mean of 5.333. Then I take the 4 numbers after that [9,0,7,8] and take the mean of them which give me a mean of 6. And so on... Exactly all the numbers should be used up as sum(indexmeans) = len(listA)

```
means = [ 5.333, 6, 7, 4]
```

Comment: Should be easy with list slicing. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`scipy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) to keep a cumulative list of indexes. Then you can `zip` that list to find corresponding starting and ending indices, while adding `0` to the front for the first starting index. Given these, you can use [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) to calculate the average of each slice.

```
>>> from numpy import mean
>>> from scipy import cumsum
>>> indexes = cumsum([0] + indexmeans)
>>> [mean(listA[i:j]) for i,j in zip(indexes[:-1], indexes[1:])]
[5.333333333333333, 6.0, 7.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using the standard libraries.

```
from __future__ import division

lst = [1,7,8,9,0,7,8,9,9,3,5,3,4,5,3]
indexmeans = [3, 4,3,5]
assert sum(indexmeans) == len(lst)

lst_copy = lst[:]
means = [sum(lst_copy.pop(0) for _ in range(i)) / i for i in indexmeans]
```